# Confused about Reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

I saw a question from four hours ago and thought I'd answer with a solution.

My answer was deleted by a moderator for just including a link and not the solution.  I understand the reasoning behind this but did not see anywhere that I would lose rep.

- You lose reputation when:
- your question is voted down: −2
- your answer is voted down: −2
- you vote down an answer: −1
- you place a bounty on a question: −full bounty amount
- one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags:−100

I **literally** just got 50 rep and was able to finally leave comments and now because I tried to help someone I've lost the privilege.

Seems a little harsh to me for just trying to help.

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the responses @Sam I am and @unit 3524344, appreciate the insight.  Sorry I cannot mark both as the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will also lose reputation if a post from which you gained reputation (i.e., it has positive votes) is deleted. The same goes for posts where you lost reputation; if deleted you gain that reputation back.

So if someone mistakenly upvoted your link-only answer, whatever reputation you gained from that has been removed now that the answer has been deleted.

If you saw a 0 score on your answer, that could be from the same number of upvotes as downvotes. Since upvotes on an answer give you 10 reputation, and downvotes remove 2, that's a net positive (all of which is erased on deletion).

(There are some circumstances where an old post with a good number of votes won't affect reputation, but that doesn't come into play here.)

Answer (score 6):

1. Deleted posts don't count toward your reputation.
2. It takes 5 downvotes on an answer to undo the reputation gain from a single upvote.  Just answer another question and get an upvote, and you'll have more than gained that reputation back.